# How to install graylog application on GCP Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, graylog, cadvisor

I am trying to install

1. CAdvisor
2. Graylog
   on Kubernetes Cluster. For now I just need to install simple application.
   But when installing graylog using Its documentation. I am getting this error

"sub process usr bin dpkg returned an error code 1"

Answer (score 0):

After which command you got this message?

Please check these links:
1- Github for [Graylog with Kubernetes and GKE](https://github.com/mouaadaassou/K8s-Graylog)
2- [Stackoverflow for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087590/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-ubuntu)